# Mysql Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = '';
$dbname = "rokon";

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname'.$dbname;

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);


$query = 'SELECT * FROM customar';
$query = $pdo->query($query);

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo $row->firstname;
    echo '<br>';
}


?>
```

I get a error while running this code the error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on
>   boolean

Comment: The query failed! Did you spell `customar` incorrectly? Should it be `customer`

Answer (score 2):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname'.$dbname;
```

Looks like you made a mistake to assign the database name. You forgot the = symbol.

Just update it to

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname;
```

Then this code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code as well it will work.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = '';
$dbname = "rokon";

try {
    $dns = "mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$dbname.";charset=utf8";
    $pdo = new PDO($dns, $user, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "PDOError: " . $e->getMessage()." In ".__FILE__;
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM customar';
$query = $pdo->query($query);

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    echo $row->firstname;
    echo '<br>';
}
```